# Tcl Expect with Putty

Tags: tcl, expect, telnet, putty

Trying to achieve a goal of running putty's plink -telnet via Tcl Expect.

When i do a regular:

```
plink -telnet 127.1.1.2
```

i get an output of the process and am able to properly conduct what i have planned.

But when i try the same from Tcl Expect:

```
% package require Expect
5.43.2
% exp_internal 1
% spawn plink -telnet 127.1.1.2 -s
16196
% expect -nocase login

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "login"? no
expect: timed out
```

there is simply no response from the piped process.

Tcl: ActiveTcl 8.6(x86)
Expect: 5.43.2
Putty: latest x86
Win10 x64

Or, if possible, could you please suggest another telnet client which works correct with tcl's expect(currently using Win7 native, but want to try something different, and yes, i know that "telnet is just a telnet", but have crash issues with the native one).

Comment: r u using ActiveTcl or Tcl in Cygwin?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to pint that - ActiveTcl